# filter to join pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark

Right now I have the following code:

```
df1 = df.filter((df.col1.isin(List1)) | (df.col2.isin(List2)))
```

I got List1 from doing `collect()` from dataframe so instead I like to use join
I tried the following

```
df1=df.filter(df.col2.isin(List2))
df2=df.join(df_List1,'col1','leftsemi')
df3=df1.join(df2,'col1' ,'outer')
```

I have two questions :

1. What is proper way to transform the original statement
2. Does it worthwhile doing performance-wise

Comment: What do you mean by "spark couldn't finish the job"? There's no job triggering code in the post

Comment: I am doing collect to check the result for df3

Comment: Have you checked the Web UI to see what's going on? How much data is this processing? What's the initial data source? Do you have enough resources to run at your expected speed? Do you use any caching at all?

Comment: The first command is working fine does it correct to use outer join at all?

Comment: Using an outer join is OK and does work. This could just be a problem with dataset size and available resources. Outer joins can produce a lot of data and chances are the cluster is struggling with that. You probably need to look at the web ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it worthwhile doing performance-wise

As always, when asking performance related questions you should test both on a real data (or one that truthfully reflects the real distribution of data) and using actual resources at your disposal.

That being said, if `List1` and `List2` are small enough `df.filter((df.col1.isin(List1)) | (df.col2.isin(List2)))` for query to succeed it is hard to expect any improvement from using `joins`, as `OR` based `JOINS` cannot be easily optimized.

There can expressed as:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM ( 
   SELECT t.* FROM t JOIN r1 WHERE t.col1 = r1.col1
   UNION
   SELECT t.* FROM t JOIN r2 WHERE t.col2 = r2.col2
)
```

or

```sql
WITH 
  t1 AS (SELECT t.* FROM t JOIN r1 WHERE t.col1 = r1.col1),
  t2 AS (SELECT t.* FROM t JOIN r2 WHERE t.col2 = r2.col2) 
SELECT * FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1  -- if col1 is an unique identifier
```

In general (we can safely omit case where `t` is small enough to be stored in memory of a single machine) both will require a full shuffle of `t`, making size of `t` a limiting factor.

Also, logical disjunction with local objects can Short-circuit evaluation when the first component is true. It is not possible to do the same in general join   case.

In future Spark should support single column `DataFrame` in `isin` ([SPARK-23945](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23945)) and optimizer should be able to make a decision between broadcast and hash join for you.